Can't add sitemap.xml to robots.txt via RobotsTxt module
First time to work with the RobotsTxt drupal module, and I'm trying to add a Sitemap entry (best SEO practices) into the : Back to site > Administration > Configuration > Search and metadata > Contents of robots.txt
Sitemap: http://<domain-of-site>.<environment>/sitemap.xml
I hit on Save configuration then heading to: http://<domain-of-site>.<environment>/robots.txt
I see no changes
Is it because of the default robots.txt file located at my /web directory or it's something else ?
PS: it'll be appreciated having how the RobotsTxt module works in drupal 10...

It's not really possible to answer this question with the information given. It could be caching. What does curl -I http://<domain-of-site>.<environment>/sitemap.xml produce?

@monalisa i'm on localhost
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-cache, private
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1469
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 23 Oct 2024 15:33:41 GMT
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Server: nginx/1.22.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Drupal-Cache: MISS
X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache: MISS
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Generator: Drupal 10 (https://www.drupal.org)
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.3.12```

That came from a Drupal module not from the static robots.txt file.

@monalisa Ok, but why adding the entry Sitemap: http://./sitemap.xml in the robots.txt in back office didn't have any effect?
plus can we use token for that to track the site-name dynamically and locales like :
Sitemap: [site:url]en/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: [site:url]fr/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: [site:url]es/sitemap.xml

On Drupal Answers each post must ask a single question.

Asking yourself is it because XY is the point where you simply need to try it. When you have an isolated development environment you can break things as much as you want and then restore it again from a backup.

It doesn’t have any effect because you haven’t deleted robots.txt, and your web server is configured to serve static files before passing the request to Drupal

Yes, you need to delete the default robots.txt file as the RobotsTxt module says prominently on its project page.

Note: You must delete or rename the robots.txt file in the root of
your Drupal installation for this module to display its own robots.txt
file(s).


from my current working directory, i can see a robots.txt but it's ignored by the VCS , it's the one dynamically generated.
and when doing :
drush config-get robotstxt.settings i have my sitemap entry added to the end of the confg (content of the robots.txt) but neither drush cex -diff nor drush cim --diff gives the expected changes in robotsTxt's config...

@tsukingo – The default robots.txt must not be there, neither ignored or not, it must physically not exist. Prevent it getting recreated: Read. It's also in the README. The RobotsTxt does not create a physical file. It creates a dynamic URL from a route and a controller with the contents from config.

Seems like I had an issue with my nginx config as i didn't tell it to fallback to drupal's routing system to fetch the appropriate robots.txt (since we are using the Robotsxt module) when there's no explicit robots.txt in the root of drupal project.
the fix is at: https://www.drupal.org/project/robotstxt/issues/1332622
and we need to make sure about robots.txt being re-created with any composer updates/installs as @leymannx pointed earlier see drupal.org/project/robotstxt/issues/3143841#comment-13734871.
